# How to show another group of column when you onclick or hover

Tags: onclick, hover

I need something like this `rchange.net`
I am looking for something that he did on the comparison table in which when you hover on a category a menu will appear. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the DOM of the document you linked, you can see that there is on the left a list of `<p>` element. You can replace them by an `<ul>`... Give them a id like `id="element-1"`.

On the right part, there is a list of `<div>` elements, each one containing a table. All divs are placed at the same place (the parent container must be `position:relative`and all divs `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;`), but only one is displayed. Give them all a common class name and a unique class name corresponding to the ID of the list element. Like `<div class="divCommonClass element-1" ... />`

Each time you hover or click a element in the list, just get the id of this element `var match = $(this).prop("id");` and look for the corresponding div. One thing you can do is, hide all divs, select the div with the class name corresponding to the ID, show it.

```
   //on click...
   var match = $(this).prop("id");
   $(".divCommonClass").hide();
   $("."+match).show();
```

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not really that knowledgeable with this stuffs and I don't want to sound like being spoonfeed either but are there any software out there that does this and gives out the html code or something so I can add it on my wordpress blog?

Comment: By the way, how do I make that vertical?